# asyncio.sleep doesnt put my loop to sleep?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I needed a task that would be done every day and since for this specific bot I'm using discord.py I'm on 3.6 and and have a lot of things on_message and on_reaction that I don't want to stop, so I'm not using time.sleep().
Someone suggested I use asyncio.sleep with a loop, because I really didnt want to use threading. I tried playing around with it to see how it works and made a simple little loop. The problem is that even though I'm trying to put it to sleep it still fires out prints (pic provided) 
!http://prntscr.com/n8ar0u

Here's what I wrote:

```
async def daily_task():
    i = 1
    while i==1:
        print('I am here to steal your women')
        asyncio.sleep(300000000000)


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(daily_task())
```

Comment: You need to `await` the `sleep` : ) `await asyncio.sleep(..)`

Comment: ... I feel really stupid right now lol. Mind posting that answer so I can close this and rid myself of this embarasment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `await` the `sleep` : )

```
await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
```

Please see [`asyncio.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep) documentation.